# Parametric plot from two NDsolve solutions

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have two independent ODE systems.

```
A = NDsolve[..., {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];
B = NDsolve[..., {a, b}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

I can draw a `ParametricPlot` from one ODE. That is,

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. A], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I wonder if I can draw a `ParametricPlot` from the two independent ODE systems. That is a `ParametricPlot` of `x[t]` taken from A and `a[t]` taken from B.

Answer (score 5):

Sure you can:

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{a'[t] == Cos[t], a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], a[t]} /. Flatten@{sol1, sol2}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The `Flatten` is there for the following reason:

```
{x[t], a[t]} /. {sol1, sol2}
(* {{{InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t],a[t]}},   
   {{x[t],InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]}}} *)
{x[t], a[t]} /. Flatten@{sol1,sol2}
(* {InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t],
    InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]} *)
```

You can also do:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t] /. First@sol1, a[t] /. First@sol2}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Awesome ssch, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use the following command:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t], a'[t] == Cos[t], a[0] == 1, 
    x[0] == 1}, {x, a}, {t, 0, 10}];

ParametricPlot[{x[t], a[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x[t], a[t]}]
```

Firstly, you may consider *one* system so as to use the `NDSolve` only one time and then use the `ParametricPlot`. It is the same if you add the equations `y[t]` and `b[t]`, as you say in your question.

So your conclutions are right!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  I formatted your answer a bit for readability.  You can check how I did this by clicking the [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/22157/edit) link just below your post.  You can also use the ? button in the top right corner of the editor to learn about how to format posts.

Comment: While theoretically it's always possible to treat two separate ODEs as one system, this may not always be beneficial.  `NDSolve` can use methods with an adaptive step size, and if you solve two equations as one system, then the same step sizes will be used for both.  I'm not exactly sure how the step size is determined.  Most likely the only "ill" effect will be that the two questions will be evaluated more than necessary.